# How to convert a data frame of integer64 values to be a matrix?

Tags: r, bit64

I have a data frame consisting entirely of [`integer64`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bit64/docs/as.integer64) columns that I'd like to convert to be a matrix.

```
library(bit64)
(dfr <- data.frame(x = as.integer64(10^(9:18))))
##                      x
## 1           1000000000
## 2          10000000000
## 3         100000000000
## 4        1000000000000
## 5       10000000000000
## 6      100000000000000
## 7     1000000000000000
## 8    10000000000000000
## 9   100000000000000000
## 10 1000000000000000000
```

Unfortunately, [`as.matrix`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/as.matrix) doesn't give the correct answer.

```
(m <- as.matrix(dfr))
##                   x
##  [1,] 4.940656e-315
##  [2,] 4.940656e-314
##  [3,] 4.940656e-313
##  [4,] 4.940656e-312
##  [5,] 4.940656e-311
##  [6,] 4.940656e-310
##  [7,] 4.940656e-309
##  [8,] 5.431165e-308
##  [9,] 5.620396e-302
## [10,] 7.832953e-242
```

The problem seems to be that `integer64` values are stored as numeric values with an "integer64" class attribute (plus some magic to make them print and do arithmetic correctly) that gets stripped by `as.matrix`.

I can't just do `class(m) <- "integer64"` because that changes the class of the matrix object not its contents.

Likewise, `mode(m) <- "integer64"` gives the wrong answer and `typeof(m) <- "integer64"` and `storage.mode(m) <- "integer64"` throw errors.

Of course I could just circumvent the problem by converting the columns to double (`dfr$x <- as.double(dfr$x)`) but it feels like there ought to be a way to do this properly.

How can I get a matrix of `integer64` values?

Comment: Perhaps you're heading down a dark path:  unless all the *functions* you're going to feed your matrix to have `integer64` methods, you'll still end up convering to doubles at some point. Does the `bit64` package have a collection of appropriate methods, and for that matter does it have some `as.matrix64`  tool?   If not you might as well convert to double or perhaps use `gmp` and `Rmpfr` packages.  ETA:  the word "matrix" doesn't even appear in the Help file for `bit64`, so I think you'll have to stick with dataframes and the available methods for that.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but ooh look at the shiny ball bouncing off into the dark, tangled woods from which there is no hope of return, maybe I should go chase it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a raw vector, assigning the `dim` attribute directly seems to work:

```
> z <- as.integer64(1:10)
> z
integer64
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
> dim(z) <- c(10, 1)
> z
integer64
      [,1]
 [1,] 1   
 [2,] 2   
 [3,] 3   
 [4,] 4   
 [5,] 5   
 [6,] 6   
 [7,] 7   
 [8,] 8   
 [9,] 9   
[10,] 10
```

For a data frame, `cbind`ing the columns also works:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=as.integer64(1:5), y=as.integer64(6:10))
> df
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
> cbind(df$x, df$y)
integer64
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    6   
[2,] 2    7   
[3,] 3    8   
[4,] 4    9   
[5,] 5    10
```

So, for an arbitrary number of columns, `do.call` is the way to go:

```
> do.call(cbind, df)
integer64
     x y 
[1,] 1 6 
[2,] 2 7 
[3,] 3 8 
[4,] 4 9 
[5,] 5 10
```