# Arithmetic with unknown number of data.table columns of non-standard type

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to create a new data.table column by adding columns whose names match a certain expression. I don't know how many columns I'll be adding. The catch is, the columns are of class 'integer64' so `rowSums(.)` does not appear to work on them.

For instance, this works for two (known) integer64 columns:

```
DT <- data.table(a=as.integer64(1:4),b=as.integer64(5:8),c=as.integer64(9:12))
DT[, y := .SD[, 1] + .SD[, 2], .SDcols=c("a", "b")]
```

And this works for my case, any number of columns, but not if their class is integer64:

```
DT[, y := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]  # gives incomprehensible data if class of a and b is integer64
```

One way I can work around it is by defining the data type of the column `y` beforehand. Is there a simpler way to do it? I may be missing something simple here and I apologize if that's so.

Comment: ```DT[, y := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]``` seem to work. It seems like the problem is cause by to `matrix` conversion that `rowSums` does.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `Reduce` is such a useful function, thank you! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: I don't think it's a general solution though. It works nicely for sum but can't handle NAs. I think either melting/dcasting the data or some general solution for to matrix transformation should be more general. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262301/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-of-integer64-values-to-be-a-matrix)